# C++ task incorrect results

Tags: c++

The Question is as follows

￼￼Write a program to prompt the user to enter an employee's salary per hour, the number of hours worked in the current week, and calculate his weekly salary. If he works more than 40 hours, his salary per hour is 1.5 times his original one for each hour over 40. From the gross pay, 6% is taken for social security tax, 14% for income tax, and 10 euros for union. If the employee has more than 2 kids, he pays 35 euro for health insurance. Calculate his weekly salary.

My code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a,b,c,kid;
    cout << "Enter his salary per hour: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the amount of hours he worked this week: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "How many kids does he have: " << endl;
    cin >> kid;

    if ( a > 40 ) {
        if (kid > 2) {
            b = (b-40)*1.5+40;
            c = a*b-a*b*20/100-10-35;
        }
        else {
            b = (b-40)*1.5+40;
            c = a*b-a*b*20/100-10;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (kid > 2)
            c = a*b-a*b*20/100-10-35; 
        else 
            c = a*b-a*b*20/100-10;
    }

    cout << c;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The code I made doesn't give me correct results. Where is it wrong ?

Comment: What results do you get and what results do you expect?

Comment: In general, it's good practice to choose descriptive names for variables. Consider changing `a` to `salaryPerHour` and `b` to `hoursWorked`

Comment: @Alan Yes, and if Chris had done that he might of noticed that `if ( salaryPerHour  > 40 )` should be `if (hoursWorked > 40)`.

Comment: @john: all part of the learning process :)

Comment: For heaven's sake give your variables sensible names. It will help you organize your thinking and avoid bugs!

Comment: For example http://screencast.com/t/a6hCekzF

Comment: I have updated my code please take a look here:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PZWkvtrZ

Comment: @ChrisSany don't make users go to an external site. Update the original question, and *add* the new code (as to not lose the original question).

Answer (score 7):

You should not use one-letter, meaningless variable names. Otherwise you would have noticed the error:

```
if ( a > 40 )
```

You wanted to compare the number of hours, but you did compare the salary.